# How do I adjust rotation based on height, ideally in css only?

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have a `::before` element that is the same size as the parent element, but rotated slightly. It is used in a number of places and the height of the parent element varies depending on content.

The problem I am having is that using (for example) `transform: rotate(-1deg);` is not enough rotation for small elements and far too much for large elements.

[Here is a jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/mu20o7ca/) (snippet below) - hover over the blue box to see what happens to the orange box when the blue box is taller.

```css
.container {
  width            : 26px;
  border           : 1px solid #999;
  display          : flex;
  justify-content  : center;
  margin           : 0 auto;
  padding          : 3px 0;
  }
.box {
  height           : 60px;
  width            : 20px;
  background       : blue;
  position         : relative;
  transition       : height 1s ease-in-out;
  }
.box:hover {
  height           :400px;
  }
.box::before {
  content          : "";
  position         : absolute;
  height           : 99%;
  width            : 99%;
  background-color : orange;
  left             : 0px;
  top              : -1px;
  transform        : rotate(-3deg);
  z-index          : -1;
  transform-origin : center center;
  }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='box'> </div>
</div>
```

How can I counter this effect such that instead of the number of degrees rotation being the constant, the pixel width from top left of the ::before and top left of the parent element is (roughly) constant? I don't need it to be exact, just not crazy when the content makes the parent element very tall.

I am trying to determine if there is a css only solution. I can figure out a way to do it with js by simply changing the rotation degrees to a number calculated based on the parent element height after content is inserted.

Alternative version, left is correct, middle is incorrect, right is correct. The heights are not defined and may change dynamically. https://jsfiddle.net/4x6qdtv7/

```css
.container {
  float: left;
  width: 26px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 3px 0;
}
.c1 .box {
  height: 60px;
}
.c2 .box {
  height: 400px;
}
.c3 .box {
  height: 400px;
}

.box {
  height: 60px;
  width: 20px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}
.box:hover {
  height:400px;
}
.c1 .box::before, .c2 .box::before {
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.c3 .box::before {
transform: rotate(-.4deg);
}
.box::before {
  content: "";
position: absolute;
height: 99%;
width: 99%;
background-color: orange;
left: 0px;
top: -1px;

z-index: -1;
transform-origin: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class='container c1'>
  <div class='box'> </div>
</div>

<div class='container c2'>
  <div class='box'> </div>
</div>

<div class='container c3'>
  <div class='box'> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: simply css calc ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()

Comment: @MisterJojo How should anyone go about to use `calc()` to solve an issue, where small heights tips a pseudo element more than if the elements height were large?

Comment: @RickardElimää by using a css variable

Comment: @MisterJojo - Can Calc mix degrees and pixels? What do I put in for the element height, given that it is unknown at the time of creating the css?

Comment: I find your question confusing and I find it difficult to fully grasp the meaning after translation. It might be clearer if you showed your solution in javascript, to see if I can transpose it to pure css. I don't really see why you change the height on a hover, instead of having 2 or 3 elements of different sizes side by side

Comment: @MisterJojo - A javascript solution would be to calculate the transform rotation as -.4deg from the height in the example in my post (400px) and update the transform in the css. Here is an example with side by side: https://jsfiddle.net/4x6qdtv7/ - the middle one is incorrect, the right one is how it should be. The heights in the example are random examples, I do not know what the final height will be of any particuar element.

Comment: I can't put snippets in a comment, and it's easier to setup and proof it in jsfiddle for me, but I should get more familiar with the snippets and use them more, I agree.

Comment: what kind of layout are you looking for? probably rotation is not needed at the end

Comment: The final intended effect is that of unshuffled paper beneath the parent element (there's a differently rotated `::after` element in the real code

Comment: show us the intended result as an image, we can do it without rotation

Comment: The intended effect is shown in the other jsfiddle I made at https://jsfiddle.net/4x6qdtv7/ - the left is correct, the middle is incorrect and the right is correct, for that height. The problem is that I don't know what the height will be when the css is created.

Comment: you will really have a blue bar like that in your site? I doubt ... I meant show us what final layout are you trying to achieve without describing the solution you made.

Comment: In the site, the blue bar is varying colors, depending on the context and contains HTML of varying length. I made this example just to highlight what I am trying to do, which is have a slightly rotated element of the same size underneath the parent element. The problem is that the amount of rotation required varies depending on the height of the parent element to prevent the rotated element from hitting the border of the containers, and stay visually about the same offset as the left side example

Comment: The final effect would be one of a stack of papers, with one slightly sticking out one way (currently using `::before` with rotation) and one the other way  (currently using `::after` with rotation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approximate this differently using `clip-path`. Resize the main container to see the result:

```css
.box {
  --d:15px;  /*adjust this */

  width:100px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:15px; /* this */
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  resize:both;
}
.box div{
  height:100%;
  background:blue;
}

.box::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  margin:5px; /* and this */
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:-1;
  background:green;
  clip-path:polygon(0 var(--d),calc(100% - var(--d)) 0,100% calc(100% - var(--d)),var(--d) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> 
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That achieves what I want! I'll have to go through the code and add the inside div everywhere which is annoying, but not a huge deal.

Comment: @BenHolness you are not obliged to have the inside div: https://jsfiddle.net/a9czms14/ .. it's for the demo to be able to use the resize

Comment: I will try and figure out how to do that, thanks!

Comment: @BenHolness check the jsfiddle I shared

Answer (score 0):

when answering I saw **Temani Afif** answer so I hesitated.
Now I tell myself that this answer can still be of interest (and it is much simpler).

It also shows how to calculate with different units

```css
.container {
  float            : left;
  width            : 26px;
  border           : 1px solid #999;
  display          : flex;
  justify-content  : center;
  margin-right     : 10px;
  padding          : 3px 0;
  --clr            : orange; 
  }
.container:hover {
  --clr  : yellow; 
  }

.c1 .box { --hgt : 100; }
.c2 .box { --hgt : 200; }
.c3 .box { --hgt : 400; }
.c1:hover .box { --hgt : 200; }
.c2:hover .box { --hgt : 400; }
.c3:hover .box { --hgt : 100; }

.box {
  height           : calc(1px * var(--hgt));
  width            : 20px;
  background       : blue;
  position         : relative;
  transition       : height 1s ease-in-out;
  }
.box::before {
  content          : "";
  position         : absolute;
  height           : 100%;
  width            : 99%;
  background-color : var(--clr);
  left             : 0;
  top              : -1px;
  transform        : rotate( calc(-500deg / var(--hgt))); /* adjust 500deg */
  z-index          : -1;
  transform-origin : center center;
  }
```

```html
<div class='container c1'>
  <div class='box'></div>
</div>

<div class='container c2'>
  <div class='box'> </div>
</div>

<div class='container c3'>
  <div class='box'> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but as I understand it still relies on fixed heights and dynamic content won't resize the boxes. The calc with different units part is interesting though!

Comment: @BenHolness so, but it's not deserving for a plus...

Comment: From what I understand of your solution, it doesn't actually resolve my problem, which is changing the amount of rotation based on a height that is not known when writing css. Did I miss something in your solution? As far as I can tell, I still have to define the heights in the css, in which case I might as well just define different rotations for each height.

Comment: @BenHolness  - yes you missed the fact that the css calc is dynamic, i added a css hover on my answer. It corresponds point to point to your initial question. And I don't understand what is the difference between indicating a height in a css variable or directly that same value on the css height, as you show in your question?

Comment: I apologise that it was not clear. In my first paragraph of my question, I said "height of the parent element varies depending on content.". In my example I did not include content as I was trying to simplify, and so I just used fixed css heights to demonstrate the issue with different heights. My point is that I want a solution that does not predefine any heights, but the rotation changes depending on the rendered height, which is calculated based on the content in the box, which is unknown when writing the css.